# How can I perform GridSearchCV but cross validate using multiple validation sets?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Train set `training_set` of `m` observations and `n` features, and I have three different validation sets `val_a`, `val_b`, and `val_c` which don't leak information to one another.

I would like to perform hyperparameter tuning via `HalvingGridSearchCV`, where I fit models on `training_set`, and validate on all three validation sets separately, and then take the score to be the average score for all three (or the lowest score).

The reason is that the three validation were observations of the samples at three distinct time points (A, B, C), and the training set contains observations from only time point A. Thus, a model trained on `training_set` and evaluated on `val_a` would not necessarily be best for `val_b` and `val_c`.

Also, concatenating all of the sets via `training_set = pd.concat([training_set, val_a, val_b, val_c])`, and then performing a variant of `GroupShuffleSplit` is non-ideal, as this results in leaking information from different time points to the model.

Thus far here's what I've tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit

# Assume each dataset has 4 observations.
tf = [-1] * len(training_set)
training_set = pd.concat([training_set, val_a, val_b, val_c])
tf += [0] * len(val_a) + [1] * len(val_b) + [2] * len(val_c)
print("Test fold:", tf)

pds = PredefinedSplit(test_fold = tf)
# gs = HalvingGridSearchCV(estimator = LGBMRegressor(), param_grid = param_grid, cv = pds, scoring = 'r2', refit = False, min_resources = 'exhaust')
for train_index, test_index in ps.split():
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Output:

```
Test fold:  [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15] TEST: [4 5 6 7]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 12 13 14 15] TEST: [ 8  9 10 11]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11] TEST: [12 13 14 15]
```

As you can see, this would generate a 3 fold cross-validation, where each validation set is left out once, and included in the training set all of the other times. I know -1 will leave the observations out of any test set, but there is no value to leave the observations out of any train set. ):

Thank you!